# Как сделать, чтобы методы в классе выполнялись в отдельном потоке?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Добрый день. Как сделать, чтобы методы, которые находятся в определённом классе выполнялись в отдельном потоке?

---

```
extends Thread
```

это не поможет?

Comment: Нужно асинхронно выполнять *каждый* вызов метода в отдельном потоке? Результат вызова нужен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

описание и пример тут: http://cybern.ru/urok-4-vozvrat-znachenij-iz-zadach-interfejs-callable.html

Comment: чтобы помочь своим ответом, желательно перевести на русский, т.к. сообщество русскоязычное

Comment: http://cybern.ru/urok-4-vozvrat-znachenij-iz-zadach-interfejs-callable.html

Comment: содержание внешних ссылок желательно дублировать в ответ, т.к. ссылка может быть/стать недоступной. также это упростит поиск ответа для автора вопроса

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, очень много там полезного)

Answer (score 3):

Надо передать в конструктор класса Threads объект твоего класса, затем переопределить метод run(), в котором и будешь вызывать свои методы. Либо реализовать интерфейс Runnable и так же переопределить метод run()(лучше вариант с Runnable т.к. тебе может понадобиться наследовать свой класс от другого класса).